# Weight things using iPhone screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, 3dtouch

Swift has `UIForceTouchCapability` class which allows to measure things' weight using iPhone screen with touch force parameter. This class is available for iPhones which have 3D touch capability.
How's it possible to get the same abilities on recent iPhones (iPhone 11, etc.) ?

Here is the code I've been using so far for this feature

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    
        if let touch = touches.first { // 1
            print(touch.maximumPossibleForce )
            print(touch.force)
                if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available { // 3
                    if touch.force >= touch.maximumPossibleForce { // 4
                        forceLabel.text = "100%+ force"
                        grammLabel.text = "385 grams"
                    } else {
                        
                        let force = (touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce) * 100 // 5
                        let grams = force * 385 / 100 // 6
                        let roundGrams = Int(grams) // 7
                        
                        forceLabel.text = "\(Int(force))% force" // 8
                        grammLabel.text = "\(roundGrams) gramms"
 
                  }
             }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        forceLabel.text = "0% force"
        grammLabel.text = "0 grams"
}
```

Now it's not working on iPhone models, which don't support 3D touch

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you mean to simulate this feature in the iPhone models that don't have the 3D Touch capability?

Comment: You can't get force touch data on phones without the hardware

Comment: I get that, the question is, how's that possible to make things work on all phones? 
Or is that possible in general?

Comment: No, it isn't possible. If the phone doesn't have the hardware you can't use the feature.